# RetrieveMultiple within a RetrieveMultiple call (causes infinite loop)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, infinite-loop

I am writing a CRM plug-in. It should be triggered on "RetrieveMultiple" message for the salesorder entity, in stage 20 (pre-operation).

The problem is that I need a list of all existing salesorders in that very pre-operation stage (in order to compare the list to a remote orders list and create new orders if needed).

To get a list of all orders, the naive approach is to use `service.retrieveMultiple(salesOrderQuery)` where salesOrderQuery is a QueryExpression on salesorder.

This causes of course dynamics 365 process to go into an infinite loop.

My question is: How can I "pre-retrieve" all salesorders in the pre-operation stage for a "RetrieveMultiple" message on salesorder without causing an infinite loop?

I am currently thinking that maybe I should change the event that causes my plug-in to be executed. My goal is to fetch all newly created orders from a remote system when the user loads the "orders" page. The only approach I have found so far is the register my plug-in step on the "RetrieveMultiple" message.

But how to get all existing orders then?

So far, my plug-in looks as follow:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PSPlugins
{
    public class RetrieveOrdersPlugin : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            var context = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext)) as IPluginExecutionContext;

            // check if pre-operation
            if (context.Stage != 20)
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Must run as pre-operation stage 20");
            if (context.MessageName != "RetrieveMultiple")
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Registered for " + context.MessageName + " only RetrieveMultiple is supported");
            if (context.PrimaryEntityName != "salesorder")
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Registered for " + context.PrimaryEntityName + " entity and only salesorder is supported");

            var tracingService = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService)) as ITracingService;
            var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory)) as IOrganizationServiceFactory;
            var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId) as IOrganizationService;

            tracingService.Trace("Plug-in RetrieveOrders executed");

            QueryExpression soQuery = new QueryExpression();
            soQuery.EntityName = "salesorder";
            soQuery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet() { AllColumns = true };

            soQuery.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
            soQuery.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;

            // The following line causes an infinite loop...
            EntityCollection entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(soQuery);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `RetrieveMultiple` message will be invoked in all places like Adv find, views, lookup, service.RetrieveMultiple calls where the system is being queried for that particular entity.

Use `Depth` property of context to [avoid infinite loops](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmbusiness/archive/2015/07/01/crm-plugins-stopping-infinite-loops-and-understanding-pluginexecutioncontext-depth).

```
if (context.Depth > 1)
    return;
```

Comment: The code now runs fine when checking `if (context.Depth > 1)`. But when debugging I experience that the line `EntityCollection entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(soQuery);` always causes a User-Unhandled exception. I don't understand why it fail retrieving the entities when debugging. It works fine when running without profiling in dynamics.